# Python Environment Carrying Over to Jobs

Tags: python, hpc

I am trying to run a software package developed that has some dependencies such as numpy on a cluster. My issue seems to be with the python environment. I have set up the environment correctly for myself locally two ways, one just with the standard python for the cluster, and then another within a virtualenv.

If I run python on the cluster, I can immediately import the required modules for the code to run, however as soon as I try to run this via a jobfile, the import issues arise. I have even sourced the virtualenv, and called which python in the jobfile to make sure it's the right environment, and it is, however import issues still arise. Does anyone have any clue if there is something I am missing?

FWIW for other people on the cluster it is working just fine, and I have even tried copying/sourcing exactly all of their environment variables, but it is not working for me. Any advice or things to check on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the path variable in both environments. It sounds like virtualenv does not have access to third party libraries

Comment: It is happening in both cases, whether I use the virtual environment or not.

So if I check the pythonpath where I'm running the job, and within the job script they are the same in both scenarios (where I use base python on the cluster, or if I try the virtual env)

Also in both scenarios, I'm fine to import modules by just starting python wherever I am and importing.

Comment: Can you post the actual issues you are getting. Also, I think this questions is more stackoverflow-y than comp. sci.

Comment: Good point I think I should probably move the question over there, my bad, new here. As for the actual issue though, the only issue I get is just the standard "module not found" type of issue you get when you try to import a module you don't have in python.

Comment: Yeah you might getter more eyes balls on your question there!

Comment: Will do, thanks very much for your help + the suggestion.

Comment: Hello again. Can you post the SIMPLEST possible example of a job file, the error messages, and your PATH variable from the shell when your python environments are loaded.

Comment: Are you sure your venv exists on the compute nodes you are running? do something like salloc -w nodename; ssh nodename; activate venv; # to ensure you can activate the virtual environment on the compute node